# Estimate the approximate position in depth of a player

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to estimate the depth position of a player in a scene taken by the Kinect sensor, in order to use this information in an algorithm that needs to evaluate the distance between a hand and the "player's body". In this case, the concept of "player's body" can be translated in a value that represents the position in depth of the player (that is what I'm looking for).

Obviously, because a person takes up a volume in the space, we know that is not possible to define a precise position of the player in the scene.

What I want to know is: what the best practise in order to calculate an approximate position in depth of a person, using the skeleton data?

I tried with the following code:

```
Skeleton playerSkeleton = (from s in skeletonData where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s).FirstOrDefault();

...

if (playerSkeleton != null)
{
    Joint head = playerSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head];

    float averagePlayerPosition = head.Z;
}
```

In the above way, I used the head depth to define the position of the player.

Is this a good choice, or is there something better (e.g. the average of several [points of the skeleton](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC584844.png))? If my choice is improvable, is there some references that justify the better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Head`, `Spine` or `HipCenter` are all decent enough points to pull out.

I would suggest the `Spine` or `HipCenter` over the head, since those two points can't move a lot unless the user moves their entire body.  That is -- you can lean forward and back to change the `Head.Z` position, but the other two points will not change as significantly unless the user physically moves their entire body.

Depending on your application's purpose the `Head` may also make sense from the user's point of view.  From your description I think this less likely, but perhaps leaning in/out to update one's overall position does fit the user's mental model.

There is a `Position` property on the `Skeleton` itself as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeleton.position.aspx

I am honestly not sure how this is calculated, as I've never used it, but you can ask for `Skeleton.Position.Z` to get a constantly calculated distance of the user according to the Kinect.

Comment: Some other people had talked about the meaning of `Skeleton.Position`, and someone said that it could be "the Center of Mass from the identified User"... See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/ee12b17d-3606-4416-8924-12fa8e482421/)

Comment: That seems apt; especially as it is available for non-active skeletons.  I looked at some previous code and actually do use this (I lied, sorry) when deciding who user to track for when I want to "closest" person.  Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SDK function, besides the one you are using, to accurately get the information.

With the 2D joint representation, you can calculate the position on the depth stream, and then just use this:

```
int realDepth = depth[index] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth
```

See the following references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.depthimageframe.playerindexbitmask.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131028.aspx#PlayerIndex